# How do I change the default application for a PDF?

Tags: gnome, file-association, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm running Redhat 5 Enterprise (Nautilus 2.16.2) with Gnome and am having trouble changing the default application for PDFs. No matter what I do, it seems to always come up as evince.

First I tried browsing to a PDF file using Nautilus, right clicking on a PDF file, selecting properties, open with, and then changing the radio button. However, the radio button is selecting "Document Viewer" and clicking on the other buttons doesn't do anything. The button is stuck on "Document Viewer" (I'd like to use Adobe Acrobat).

I thought I'd do it manually then. Running `gnomevfs-info file.pdf" shows:

```
Name              : file.pdf
MIME type         : application/pdf
Default app       : evince.desktop
```

`xdg-mime query default application/pdf` used to show the same result but after running `xdg-mime default AdobeReader.desktop application/pdf` it now shows this:

```
AdobeReader.desktop
```

So now `xdg-mime` and `gnomevfs-info` are showing different default applications for this file type. I've tried updating the mime database using `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime` as well as updating my desktop database using `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share` but nothing seems to be working.

Changing a default application really shouldn't be this difficult. What should I try next to change my default application?

, however, shows something different

My `.local/share/applications/defaults.list` file, however, shows the following:

```
application/pdf=AdobeReader.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to click on the actual radio button, not just the different entries in the listbox.